# Having trouble with SetParent and SendMessage routines

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, mfc

My environment is Winforms .NET 4.0.  I'm running two routines: SetParent & SendMessage.  The routines are defined as such:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, uint wParam, uint lParam);
```

The routines are used to force a window from a foreign process into a Winforms tab.  Here is the code we use:

```
SetParent(procSlic3r.MainWindowHandle, Main.main.TPSlic3r.Handle);
SendMessage(procSlic3r.MainWindowHandle, 274, 61488, 0);//panelSlic3r
setupwindow("Slic3r", Main.main.TPSlic3r);

public void setupwindow(string processWindow, Control ParentControl)
    {  
        IntPtr hwndChild = FindWindow(null, processWindow);
        if (FindWindow(null, processWindow).ToInt32() < 1)
        {
            return;//no process by this name found
        }
        SetParent(hwndChild, ParentControl.Handle);

        Point PZero = new Point(0, 0);
        SetWindowPos(hwndChild, (IntPtr)(-1), ParentControl.PointToScreen(PZero).X, ParentControl.PointToScreen(PZero).Y,
                                ParentControl.Width, ParentControl.Height, SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS + SWP_FRAMECHANGED + SWP_SHOWWINDOW);//+SWP_NOOWNERZORDER);
        SendMessage(hwndChild, 274, 61488, 0);//tell them to expand please
    }
```

This code works fine on 32bit Windows 8.1 / Windows 10, but it doesn't work in 64 bit Windows 10.  Instead the child window disappears and the tab stays blank.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SendMessage.html

Comment: This is a step in the right direction, but it doesn't complete the gap.  What message am I supposed to call?  How do I know what IntPtr/INT/LONG value to use?  How do I access the lookup tables they mention?

Comment: See [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/04/12/10410454.aspx) and [AttachThreadInput is like taking two threads and pooling their money into a joint bank account](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/06/19/10426841.aspx).  Short version: there's no safe way to do that.

Comment: I do it all the time in x86 Windows.